# How to format a name

Tags: python

I'm taking a class on python and the lab assignment asks...

Many documents use a specific format for a person's name. Write a program whose input is:

```
firstName middleName lastName
```

and whose output is:

```
lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial.
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
Pat Silly Doe
```

the output is:

```
Doe, P.S.
```

If the input has the form:

```
firstName lastName
```

the output is:

```
lastName, firstInitial.
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
Julia Clark
```

the output is:

```
Clark, J.
```

So far I have...

```
firstName = input()
middleName = input()
lastName = input()
lastName2 = input()
firstName2 = input()

print(lastName+ ',', (firstName[0])+'.'+(middleName[0])+'.')
```

on the test screen, it says it outputs as Doe, P.S. but when I go to the submit screen it says there's no output. I don't get any of this.

This is the error message I'm getting

```
0 / 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    middleName = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Input
Pat Silly Doe
Your output
Your program produced no output
Expected output
Doe, P.S.
```

Comment: Perhaps they are expecting you to write a function that returns the required output. E.g. `def format_name(lastName, middleName, lastName): return lastName+ ',', (firstName[0])+'.'+(middleName[0])+'.'` ?  Printing writes to the console but does not return anything.

Comment: What are `lastName2` and `firstName2` supposed to be?  Your code is certainly not being given five inputs, in fact there may only be one (which you'd have to split into its parts).

Comment: Why do you call `input` 5 times? My interpretation of the task is, that "firstName middleName lastName" has to be given in one input.

Comment: I don't think the assignment expects you to try and read five lines of input.

Comment: The last two lines of input are for the Julia and Clark. Thats what confuses me. Am I supposed to add those to the "print function" too?

Comment: You're supposed to read one line of input. Split it into names that are separated by space. Then determine if they gave 2 or 3 names, so you can produce the appropriate output.

Comment: Surely the purpose of this assignment is to see if you understand concepts that they already taught, such as the `str.split()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question says that the input is all on one line. Each call to `input()` reads a whole line of input. So your solution requires 5 lines of input to be provided -- 3 for a person with 3 names, and 2 for a second person with only 2 names.

You should just call `input()` once to get the whole name. Use `split()` to break it into a list at the whitespace separators. Then you can produce the appropriate output depending on the length of the list.

```
names = input().split()
if len(names) == 3:
    first_name, middle_name, last_name = names
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.{middle_name[0]}.')
elif len(names) == 2:
    first_name, last_name = names
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.')
else:
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: This code is producing an "Invalid input". I'm trying to study it to see what it is doing.

Edit: I found out what was wrong. I had returns in my input.

Comment: I tested it and it works. What did you type as input?

Comment: I tried both your sample inputs and they produced the desired output.

Comment: Here is a more flexible approach just to show the power of Python : `*first_names, last_name = input().split()` followed by `print(f'{last_name}, {".".join(first_name[0] for first_name in first_names)}.')`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that you haven't wrote the input.
I run it and it works just fine
[![That's just running your code][1]][1]

However, I see a problem and it's that you're asking first nime twice and last name too and not really using them. Please let me know if I did help you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2jiq.png

Comment: Don't post images, paste the transcript into a code block.

Comment: Yes. When you run what I've written it returns what they are asking for on the development screen. The problem is on the submit screen it says "your program produced no output" so I don't think it's what they're asking for. 


0 / 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    middleName = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Input
Pat Silly Doe
Your output
Your program produced no output
Expected output
Doe, P.S.

Comment: Ahhh, ok then you receive a string then split it using the split() method and store that in a list, then you have on your list ['Pat', 'Silly', 'Doe'] so you can do the thing you were trying to in first place. Something like:
full_name=input()
name=list(full_name.split())
print (...)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

First_Name

Middle_Name

Last_Name

Put the input as:

First_Name Middle_Name Last_Name

I had my program written just fine when I did it, but I was putting the names on separate input lines, once I entered the entire name on ONE line for input, then it ran perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my answer:

```
full_name = input().split()

if len(full_name) == 2:
    first_name = full_name[0]
    last_name = full_name[1]
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.')
elif len(full_name) == 3:
    first_name = full_name[0]
    middle_name = full_name[1]
    last_name = full_name[2]
    print(f'{last_name}, {first_name[0]}.{middle_name[0]}.')
```